# Neural Networks without dynamics

Tags: r, dynamic, neural-network

I am using neuralnet and nnet packages. I have a data with 26 variables and 17 of them are binary data, and 9 of them are continuous. My predicted variable is a continuous. I have 1279 observation in train data. My first test vector is a known data and other are predictions made in iterations. Data are normalized on Z-score and than scaled on [0, 1]. All variables are class xts() even binary ones.

```
>model <- neuralnet(formula,
             data = train_data, hidden = 2, threshold = 5*10^-3, stepmax = 2000000,
             algorithm = "backprop", learningrate = 0.001, linear.output = F, rep = 4, 
             act.fct = "logistic")
```

and than I am making a predictions in a for loop

```
>for(i in 1:length(test_data)){
    new_prediction <- compute(model, last_prediction, rep = best)
    re_scaled_and_renormalized <- new_prediction
    test_data[i,] <- re_scaled_and_renormalized
    new_vector <- calculating_other_parameters(re_scaled_and_renormalized)
    last_prediction <- normalized(scaled(new_vector))
}
```

There are result on a test set.

```
Real    Predicted
14.50   14.32869879
14.51   14.38411842
14.97   14.41794784
14.74   14.45243153
14.74   14.49286739
14.33   14.52317526
14.03   14.53298749
14.02   14.52977663
13.91   14.57668540
13.90   14.61568341
13.05   14.64826698
13.12   14.70308401
13.41   14.77500693
13.49   14.90128834
13.35   15.03657559
13.51   15.15863558
14.01   15.27185599
13.94   15.35757182
14.15   15.45064387
14.25   15.53207570
14.16   15.59686009
```

Results I get on train set are quite good (nicely fitted). There is dynamics in results (the results on train set are well fitted to real data), but on test set there is no dynamics there (real data is  time series function with ups and downs but predicted data is quite similar to regression line). And the same problem I get if I use nnet(). Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide your data and code? Hard to tell like this...

Comment: What do you mean by "there is dynamics"?